# Xcode problem AppDelegate with Firebase - 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer'

Tags: swift, swiftui

newbie in UIKit/SwiftUI here, now I'm working on a SwiftUI App with UIKit Life Cycle and I got this problem

```
Cannot find type 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer' in scope
```

The code is that:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        //nothing
    }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = { **Here is problem**
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "app_Swiftui")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get Build Failed everytime and I get this error. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I don't think that `NSPersistendCloudKitContainer` is in Firebase. It's actually in `CloudKit` (Apple's own storage). import CloudKit and see how it works.

Comment: same problem, 'Cannot find type 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer' in scope' and i imported CloudKit.

Comment: Try CoreData. Double checked the documentation and it seems like a CoreData

Comment: That's it man! Thank you so much! 
Post answer here and let me vote your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSPersistendCloudKitContainer` is a `CoreData` class.

`import CoreData` and you'll be on your way!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: 
`NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` is a subclass of `NSPersistentContainer` capable of managing both CloudKit-backed and noncloud stores.

> So its a Core Data!

Declarer it on top:

```
import CoreData
```

For more details read this page [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack) also this can help [Apple Doc2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer)